# Simple regular expression with repetition has me stumped

Tags: regex, repeat

Greetings.

So simple a problem has me stumped.  People here are so helpful.

I am trying to match a string containing some fixed text and random digits.

```
echo blah blah abc123 | grep -o abc
abc

echo blah blah abc123 | grep -o abc[0-9]
abc1

echo blah blah abc123 | grep -o abc[0-9]+

echo blah blah abc123 | grep -o "abc[0-9]+"

echo blah blah abc123 | grep -o "abc[0-9]*"
abc123

echo blah blah abc123 | grep -o abc[0-9]{3}

echo blah blah abc123 | grep -o "abc[0-9]{3}"
```

The * operator (matches zero or more times) is the only one that works as I would expect.

Why does the + operator (match 1 or more times) not match?

Why does the specific repetition count operator {3} not match?

I am running these examples in a bash shell under Ubuntu 10.10 if it makes a difference.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They both work when you escape the special characters:

```
$ echo blah blah abc123 | grep -o "abc[0-9]\+"
abc123
$ echo blah blah abc123 | grep -o "abc[0-9]\{3\}"
abc123
```

Unescaped, the regex is looking for a literal `+` or `{`, as you have probably deduced.

As to exactly why you have to keep a `*` unescaped but you have to escape a `+`, I'm not sure.

Comment: Now I understand the meaning of the grep man page "... In  basic  regular  expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?,
       \+, \{, \|, \\(, and \\)"

Comment: BTW, I really like stackoverflow.

Comment: The problem is that, by default, `grep` uses this (limited) version of regexen.  Use `egrep` or `grep -E` to get the regex syntax you want.